# Azure Data Flow store SHA256 product in a SNOWFLAKE Binary field

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to store the output of this transformation: sha2(256,"Some value") into snowflake.
The target column is of type BINARY.

I am running into errors such as:

Binary value '6228F...' is too long and would be truncated.

and

string is not a legal hex encoded value.

What the correct conversion here to get the digest stored in a binary column?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toBinary(sha2(256,"my data"))

Check your BINARY field in snowflake is BINARY(64) not BINARY(16).